ML. How to make a neural network remember the context and data?
I want the neural network to be able to remember, but a perceptron can only remember something during training, but I want the neural network to adapt to new conditions without retraining, for example, if I said that my name is Nikolai, it remembered it, or if green mushrooms were useful in the game before, but then became poisonous, it stopped eating them, and then, if they returned to normal, it started eating them again. I thought about LSTM, but this is a recurrent neural network, and people seem to be abandoning them in favor of transformers?

Very interesting question (+1). A few ideas come to mind….Have you thought about a transformer with “external memory”, or Neural episodic memory ?

@RobertLong, -?

Hi Nikolai  Does that mean “no” ?

@RobertLong, site just opened strangely and instead of an answer there was only your name and a dash "–
Robert Long
", I do not know why

Nikolai, it must be the StackExchange gremlins ‍♂️Can you read my comment now ?

@RobertLong, now - yes
